# Change element type depending on src file extension type

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Goal: If custom element type (ex. `<media ...>`) has one of several `src` file extensions (ex. `m4v`, `jpg` ...), change the custom element type to reflect the proper element to display `src` appropriately.

I think maybe my jquery selector for the `media` element could be the problem?

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function($) {
    $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
        var attrs = {};

        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
        });

        this.replaceWith(function() {
            return $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
        });
    }
    })(jQuery);


    $("media").has('[src$=".jpg"]').changeElementType("img");
    $("media").has('[src$=".m4v"]').changeElementType("video");
});
```

So far when running this, Chrome console reports jQuery errors... but as far as I can tell everything is declared properly. Syntax or misunderstanding of something?

edit: here is the error report

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
(anonymous function)
l jquery.min.js:2
c.add jquery.min.js:2
v.fn.v.ready jquery.min.js:2
v.fn.v.init jquery.min.js:2
v jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
v.extend.globalEval jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
v.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
v.fn.extend.domManip jquery.min.js:2
v.fn.extend.append jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
v.extend.access jquery.min.js:2
v.fn.extend.html jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
l jquery.min.js:2
c.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
T jquery.min.js:2
r
```

• This is running in a Wordpress noConflict mode

Comment: Which line is related to this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

**EDIT**

I made minor adjustments to the output of the element and image tags. it was outputting `<img></img>` which is invalid. Please see the updated fiddle

<del>http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/TjGzZ/</del>

http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/TjGzZ/3/

just some minor tweaks.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $.fn.changeElementType = function (newType) {

        if (!this.length) return;    // added

        var attrs = {};

        $.each(this[0].attributes, function (idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.name] = attr.value;
        });

        this.replaceWith(function () {

            var element = $('<' + newType + '/>', attrs);

            if (newType !== 'img')
                element.append($(this).contents());

            return element;
        });
    };

    $('media[src$=".png"]').changeElementType('img');    // changed slightly
    $('media[src$=".m4v"]').changeElementType('video');    // changed slightly
});
```

rather then

`$("media").has('[src$=".jpg"]').changeElementType("img");`

that was changed to

`$('media[src$=".png"]').changeElementType('img');`

and of course you can change `.png` with whatever you want, i just used a png for testing.

The plugin has one small tweak also, just checking to see if that element existed, if not don't do anything. If that check wasn't there it would yell at you because it would try and get attributes on an undefined element.